# Question regarding the ExtJS License

Tags: licensing, extjs

Let's say I create a CMS that uses ExtJS.

I want to avoid the license fee, so I open-source the CMS on github.

Now let's imagine that I make your friend Dave a website that uses my CMS.  I spend three hundred hours designing a logo and layout.  Can I charge a fee for this, and would I be obliged to open-source Dave's website too or is it enough to just open-source the CMS?

I find this LPGL license a little confusing.  Say hi to Dave for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only ExtJS code prior to 2.1 is under LGPL.  It currently uses [GPLv3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html).  That means if you *distribute* it, "the entire work, as a whole" must be licensed under GPLv3.  The entire work may include code directly connected to ExJS.  But "separate and independent works, which are not by their nature extensions of the covered work" (which probably includes server code) don't have to be GPLv3.  So the way I interpret it, only code (e.g. client JS you develop) that tightly extends Ext would have to be released.  See also [this FAQ](http://www.extjs.com/products/license-faq.php#mod).

Regardless, you can charge as much as you want for services and/or the CMS itself.

IANAL.

Answer (score -1):

ExtJS GPL Licence means that if you are using ExtJS under GPL Licence, and not modifying ExtJS itself, then  you are Free to use ExtJS in whatever manner on any Website. But if you take ExtJS and start modifying ExtJS itself ( to make some better 'Super-Duper-ExtJS' Library ), then you have to share that with everyone, because if you start selling 'Super-Duper-ExtJS' to your Clients, then whats going to happen is that 'ExtJS-Company' finds itself Competing with Itself. I dont think you need to share your 'Website's Source-code' in any case. If you need to share your 'Websites source-code' ifself with other People while using ExtJS-GPL, then only the ExtJS-GPL Licence would start looking absurd, and you need to start looking at jQueryUI or DOJO ! But I dont think that 'ExtJS-Company' means to share your Websites-source just for the reason that you used their ExtJS Library ! What say .......

Comment: That's incorrect and bad advice - you don't have to modify ExtJS code to fall under the GPL conditions. And please don't post the same answer multiple times. Flag questions as duplicates if they have the same answers.

Comment: http://sencha.com/legal/open-source-faq See the following Main FAQ's 1) What Sencha products are available under the GPL v3? 2) What am I not allowed to do with code that is released under the GPL v3? 3) What is a modification? So, from my understanding of GPL3, If you modify ExtJS heavily and try to re-sell Super-ExtJS itself (not your Website), then you have to share the Code for that Super-ExtJS whatever your purpose. The Licence applies to ExtJS Libraries only. I maybe wrong ofcourse. I prefer jQuery :)

Comment: "I may be wrong of course"... then don't post this type of advice. And I repeat, don't post the same answer over and over again.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. Please see other accepted answers that you've pasted this response to. GPL is a complex topic and your answer misses the mark.

Comment: Any Licence applies during 'Distribution'. For e.g. Varien used ExtJS to create Magento-CE backend, and when they distributed Magento-CE, they did so under GPL so that to whoever they distribute the source to they comply with GPL. But when Ecommerce-Store-Owners download and create Websites using Magento-CE, they dont Distribute their Website-Sources to their 'Customers', because using a Website isnt exactly Distribution. Otherwise expect every Magento-CE Store-Owner to distribute their Website-sources as Newyear Bonus to their Customers.